# What is a concrete example of a non-compact Hermitian operator on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space whose eigenvectors do not form a complete set?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

If I am not misunderstanding anything: by the spectral theorem, Hermitian operators that act upon finite-dimensional Hilbert space as well as compact Hermitian operators that act upon infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces have eigenvectors that form a complete set. I would like an example of a Hermitian operator whose eigenvectors do not do so.

Answer (score 7):

For example, multiplication by $x$ on $L^2[0,1]$.  It has continuous spectrum $[0,1]$ and no eigenvectors.

Comment: My apologies--I think I misstated the question, I meant to ask about a complete set of eigenvectors, not a complete set of eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought you meant.